# getSharePointSiteUsageDetail Report does not return Site URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, reporting

When looking the SharePoint Site Usage detail reports (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) the Site URL parameter is always empty.

This is true for both calling the report graph api endpoint ([https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D7')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period=%27D7%27))) and when browsing the report in the admin portal (https://admin.microsoft.com/#/reportsUsage/SharePointSiteUsageV1)

I have checked several different tenants and the behaviour is the same for all. I've also tried with switching the deanonymizing on/off with no effect either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this looks like it is a known issue that's been happening for a while.

There is currently an open service health advisory at

https://admin.microsoft.com/#/servicehealth/:/alerts/SP676147

Title: Admins may see incomplete usage reports for SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business

User impact: Admins may see incomplete usage reports for SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business.

More info: SharePoint and OneDrive URLs may not be displayed in some usage reports. The following report types may be impacted:

- SharePoint site usage reports
- OneDrive for Business site usage reports
- Data Access Governance (DAG) impact was remediated on Saturday, October 21, 2023, reports created during the impact timeframe can be re-generated to include URLs.

As a workaround, admins with appropriate access can use the SharePoint REST API or Microsoft Graph API to retrieve information about site IDs referenced in the affected reports.